# C program: automate a single linkedlist with given length

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So I am new to linkedlist and I want to create a code that automatically creates a single linkedlist, given the head and the size of the list. Each block has an integer variable `val` and the pointer `next`. The entire code looks like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    /* create a struct with name: mynode */
    typedef struct node{
       int val;
       struct node *next;
    } mynode;

    void populateList(mynode *head, int length){
      mynode *current, *nextblock;
      current = (mynode*)malloc(sizeof(mynode));
      nextblock = (mynode*)malloc(sizeof(mynode));

      current = head;       /* start at the head for current */

      for (int i  = 0; i < length; i++) {
        current->val = i;
        nextblock = current->next;
        current = nextblock;    
      }
      current->next = NULL;     /* for last block */
    }

/* print the list */
void printList(mynode *head){
  mynode *current = head;   /* start at the first node, which is HEAD */

  while (current != NULL) {
    printf("%d\n", current->val);
    current = current->next;    /* current is now the next block */
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(){

  /* local variable head points to 1st item in list */
  mynode *head = NULL;
  head = (mynode*)malloc(sizeof(mynode));

  if (head == NULL) {
    return 1;
  }
  populateList(head,5);
  printList(head);

  return 0;
}
```

The function `populateList` is what I want to ask. My logic is to rewrite the current block and then assign value. After the for loop ends, current should be at the last block, so I assign the last block pointer to point to NULL. This causes a seg fault.  Is there a way to end the list using the for loop? Please let me know.

The problematic function is this:

```
void populateList(mynode *head, int length){
      mynode *current, *nextblock;
      current = (mynode*)malloc(sizeof(mynode));
      nextblock = (mynode*)malloc(sizeof(mynode));

      current = head;       /* start at the head for current */

      for (int i  = 0; i < length; i++) {
        current->val = i;
        nextblock = current->next;
        current = nextblock;    
      }
      current->next = NULL;     /* for last block */
    }
```

**Update 1**

So I think I solve the seg fault problem.  However, how do I return that new linked list so that my `printList` function can print it out? It cant be a void, I just do not know what the type of the function would be.
With the fix, `printList` only prints out the last block, which is 4 in this case because I loop from `i = 0; i < 5`. Below is the fix for the seg fault:

```
void populateList(mynode *head, int length){
  mynode *current = head;
  mynode *nextblock;   

  for (int i  = 0; i < length; i++) {
    current->val = i;
    nextblock = (mynode*)malloc(sizeof(mynode));
    current->next = nextblock;
    nextblock = current;
  }
  current->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest stepping through your code with a debugger, in addition to really thinking about what you're trying to accomplish.  For example, why are you assigning the result of `malloc` to `current`, then a few lines later doing `current = head` which causes a leak?

Comment: Another thing to think about - right now, regardless of the length of your desired linked list, you will only ever call `malloc` twice - shouldn't there be a `malloc(sizeof(mynode))` call for each of the nodes?

Comment: I'd expect `nextblock = (mynode*)malloc(sizeof(mynode));` to be in the `for()` loop.

Comment: Tip: recommend to drop the unneeded cast and size to the referenced type.  `current = (mynode*)malloc(sizeof(mynode));` --> `current = malloc(sizeof *current);`

Comment: Also rather than a populate list all in one function, write a `add_node` that simply allocates for a node, initializes `val` to a given value, sets `next` to `NULL` and add that node at the tail of the list. Then you can just call `add_node` from `populate_list` as needed (and still have a working `add_node` for normal list use). A similar example would be [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB), A better approach is to maintain a `head` and `tail` node so additions at the end are trivial [Singly Linked List of Integers](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A)

Comment: Your populateList function is still wrong.  The way it is written, current is NEVER changed.  Check this, https://onlinegdb.com/BysL7aH8I